# Finding the coefficient of a variable in a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots\cdots(x-10)$.

How do I approach such problems?

Comment: To save calculation time, note that $(1+2+\cdots+10)^2=1^2+2^2+\cdots+10^2$ plus twice the sum of the products taken two at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On looking at the polynomial you should come to a conclusion that if exponent of $x$ is $8$, then $x$ is multiplied by itself $8$ times and by $2$ numbers as there are $10$ terms to be multiplied.

So the coefficient will be, 
$$1.2+1.3+...+2.3+2.4+...+3.4+3.5+...+8.9+8.10+9.10$$

which is the sum of product of $2$ numbers taken at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the coefficient of $x$ of each factor of the polynomial is $1$.

Hence, what you want is the sum of the product of every distinct two of $-1,-2,\cdots,-10.$

Answer (score 1):

Or written in short form

$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le 10}i\cdot j=\sum_{j=2}^{10}\left(j\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i\right)$$

which you now can simplify using the formula for sums of arithmetic and quadratic sequences.

---

PS: The comment by André Nicolas provides an even faster method, which can be generalized using Newton identities.